# css style depend on differrent breakpoints

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

ref: [Display helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/)

Is there a way to change differrent css style dynamically depend on size of current breakpoint.
Something like when windows are current on xs  size/position/color are differ from md and so on....

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vuetify utility classes, you insert the breakpoint in the class name. `pa-2` defaults for `xs` and up, to change it to `pa-4` from `md` breakpoint up, you apply both `pa-2` and `pa-md-4` to your element. Same goes for all other predefined utility classes for [spacing](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/), [text](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/), [colors](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/), etc.

For applying your own classes in vue without repeating the breakpoint settings in each component (and duplicating/decentralising breakpoint management), you can either:

- [Set classes dynamically](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service) with a computed property that returns a string of classes based on the value of `this.$vuetify.breakpoint`

```
<template>
  <div :class="userCardClasses" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  computed: {
    userCardClasses() { 
      if (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp) return 'userCard userCard--md'
      // You can check the value of the helpers (mdAndUp) or write a switch/case for this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name
      return 'userCard userCard--xs'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.userCard {
  padding: 8px;
}

.userCard--xs {
  background-color: blue;
}

.userCard--md {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

- [Import Vuetify breakpoint variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#usage-in-templates) in your component and use them when writing media queries.

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';

  .custom-class {
    display: block
  }

  @media #{map-get($display-breakpoints, 'md-and-down')}
    .custom-class {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This is close to fix my problem.but if i want to be more specific.Ex. Varie on screen size"pixel-width-range" how can i do that?

Comment: You'll want to avoid that when possible, as you'll end up with separate breakpoint definitions all across your different components which is a nightmare and doesn't work with the breakpoint service from vuetify. If you want to change the values provided by vuetify for their breakpoints, you can do so by changing the default values to those you want to use: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#thresholds

Comment: and if you don't care about maintainability, you can simply write your own media queries without importing the vuetify variables.

Comment: It is as you comment.when i  commit code to my senior.It end up as i overdoing it.As my project is desktop app.Get a good result in 1920x1080 and 1600x900 is enough. Thank you for you comment.